# text after floated element not filling properly

Tags: html, css, text

i used a filler image with the same dimensions and it has no transparency or you'd see the menu.  but the menu isn't the issue.  the text is.  check out this fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/WhiteRau/DC78P/' and you'll see what i mean.

here is the entire code:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
        nav {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            margin: 4px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
            z-index: 6;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        nav ul li {
            background: #d5b079;
            font-size: 24px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            padding: 4px 20px 6px 20px;
        }
        nav ul li:hover, nav ul li:active {
            background: #434459;
        }
        #holder {
            display: inline-block;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
        #theBossMan {
            width: 450px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            left: -220px;
            top: -120px;
            border: 2px solid green;
            pointer-events: none;
            z-index: 8;
        }
        #content {
            background: #d5b079;
            color: white;
            text-align: justify;
            border: 1px solid red;
            margin: 4px;
            width: 480px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            position: relative;
            left: 400px;
            z-index: 4;
        }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="group">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="holder">
    <img id="theBossMan" src="http://image0-rubylane.s3.amazonaws.com/shops/colemanscollectibles/03660.1L.jpg" alt="it's a placeholder">
    <section id="content">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
        <h2>so glad you could come</h2>
        <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, ducimus harum molestias quis enim delectus corrupti alias provident adipisci atque dicta quidem reiciendis tenetur perferendis quasi odit minus sed natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, est, vel ducimus perferendis atque praesentium culpa ratione veritatis nam cupiditate unde sequi molestias neque veniam voluptas soluta porro dolorum reprehenderit!</span></p>
    </section>
</section> <!-- end of HOLDER  -->'
```

what is going on here?  the text should be by the spoon. it's not floated, so a clearfix yeilds no love (tried it anyway, just in case...).  the box outlines are for reference... i do not understand why the text is down at the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

Your example is rather confusing because your use of css positioning is madness and requires completely rewriting. **But** to use your example it is because of you `nav` element; see your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/DC78P/1/.

When you hover over the nav (I added some css to “hide” it), you’ll see that your body of text jumps up to normal because the `<section>` tag is actually sitting below your `nav` element so the text element is actually correctly placed. It is your use of positioning that is wildy placing all of the other elements outside of their parent containers…

Perhaps try:

http://learnlayout.com/index.html

Comment: madness it may appear to be, but i know of no other way to achieve the layered look and functionality the client wants.  and i'm sorry, but all your fiddle does is move everything over to the left; it doesn't actually move the text up beside the 'spoon' at all.  however, you've pointed me at something else that may lead to a solution.

Comment: You've negatively positioned the spoon up outside of it's container so surely doing the same to the `#content` element would align it for you? Aka: `#content{ top : -120px; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem

```
<section id="holder">
    <img id="theBossMan"
```

Because the img is in the section it pushes down your text. if you remove the image you will see the text appears properly.

edit:

how about this:

```
<nav class="group">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="holder">
    <img id="theBossMan" src="http://image0-rubylane.s3.amazonaws.com/shops/colemanscollectibles/03660.1L.jpg" alt="it's a placeholder">
</section>
<section id="content">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
    <h2>so glad you could come</h2>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>
</section>
```

now it is outside the section and already works better. the img is stil there only not in the same section as the text.

Comment: i think it's pretty obvious the image needs to be there...  not helpful.

Comment: maybe you should think about replacing it to an other location in the html. you can say this aint helpful. i don's see why it needs to be at the exact location as it is. place the img outside the section and stile it to be at the right location. if you say ware the image needs to be ill give it a try. thanks for the -1 btw.

Comment: There is not enough info in this question so giving rep back